# Entity Framework: Ignoring a field on Insert only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an extra field in my model called StatusChange, this is populated using a sproc to fetch all fields from the table as well as the extra field StatusChange

```
SELECT New.*, [dbo].[ftn_GetStatusChange](Old.MemberStatusId, New.MemberStatusId) AS StatusChange
FROM Member New
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member Old ON New.MemberNo = Old.MemberNo AND Old.ImportHistoryID = @ImportIdToCompare
WHERE New.ImportHistoryID = @NewestImportId
```

Here is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ftn_GetStatusChange]
(
    @OldStatus char,
    @NewStatus char
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@OldStatus IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END

    IF (@OldStatus = 'R') 
        BEGIN
            IF @NewStatus = 'C' RETURN 5
            IF @NewStatus = 'S' RETURN 4
        END

    IF (@OldStatus = 'C')
        BEGIN
            IF @NewStatus = 'R' RETURN 3
            IF @NewStatus = 'S' RETURN 4
        END

    IF (@OldStatus = 'S')
        BEGIN
            IF @NewStatus = 'C' RETURN 5
            IF @NewStatus = 'R' RETURN 3
        END

    RETURN 0
END
```

This is the enum that the numbers map to

```
public enum StatusChange
    {
        NoChange = 0,
        New = 1,
        Current = 2,
        Resigned = 3,
        Suspended = 4,
        Reinstated = 5,
    }
```

The Database table doesn't have the field StatusChange though as there is no need for it, so I tried adding the attribute Computed to the property in C#

This is the C# code

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public StatusChange StatusChange { get; set; }
```

However when I call SaveChanges() on the DbContext I get the error

```
Invalid column name 'StatusChange'.
```

Is there anyway I can have this property for SELECT only and ignore it on INSERT?

Comment: Can you add a `[NotMapped]` attribute to the property? Or will that also cause the property to not be set when loaded?

Comment: I tried this but then the SPROC doing the SELECT ignores the StatusChange property.

Comment: by the looks of it you will need to change your design to make this work. Can you not use [NotMapped] and fetch the info you need and then do StatusChange separately. Like just include the field in the select Old.MemberStatusId, New.MemberStatusId and at run time convert to statuses,

Comment: @Seabizkit I get your point but then I'll need to change the model to have old and new MemberStatusId, which would mean the insert would still fail as I would only be inserting one of these....

Comment: hey sozs but not sure how the insert would fail. could you explain further. The insert could be done on a separate call...seeing as you are doing a custom select.. can you maybe not get what you want by using navigation props and eager loading..

Comment: @Seabizkit - Are you suggesting creating a model for the Status and have that participate in the nav props?

Comment: please include what the ftn_GetStatusChange does... so i can see how I would do it in a pure ef way.

Comment: Hey @Seabizkit - I edited the question to add in the function, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey thanks i will look at this later but could you please include a comment next to 1, 0 , 5 ,3, and 4 as to what they represent... so wen done in code its easier to read and understand.

Comment: Hey @Seabizkit - I have added in the enum that the numbers map to, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is **not tested** and is **not 100% what you want** as its quite hard to visualize your data without actually having it... but maybe this helps...

Please take with a pinch of salt its quite hard to visualize your data and requirements ;-)

```
public class Member
{
    [Key][AutoIncromentCode]
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public string MemberNo {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public int MemberStatusId { get; set;}

    public int ImportHistortId { get; set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public MemberStatus
    {
        return (Status)MemberStatusId
    }
}

public enum Status
{
    NoChange = 0,
    New = 1,
    Current = 2,
    Resigned = 3,
    Suspended = 4,
    Reinstated = 5,
}

public class MemberStatusDto
{
    public Member NewMember {get; set;}
    public Member OldMember {get; set;}
}

public void GetSomeStuff(int importHistortId )
{
    List<MemberStatusDto> result  = ( from N_Memeber in Content.Member
                                      join O_Member in Content.Member on 
                                      new { N_Memeber.MemberNo, O_Member.ImportHistortId } equals new {MemberNo = O_Member.MemberNo, ImportHistortId = importHistortId }
                                      into T_Members
                                      from A_Members in T_Members.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      where N_Memeber.ImportHistoryID = importHistortId
                                     select new MemberStatusDto()
                                     {
                                        NewMember = A_Members.N_Memeber,
                                        OldMember = A_Members.O_Member
                                     }).Tolist();               

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        var NewState = item.NewMember.MemberStatus;
        var oldState = (item.OldMember == null) ? "nothing" : item.OldMember.MemberStatus

    }
}
```

Comment: Personally it would be much better if you moved all History Items in to another table! and then you could use EF to auto link this and arrange by date wen you pull back a member... that would be a much smarter design.